# HTML5 date input control custom validation based on JSON Schema

Tags: html, validation, date, backbone.js

In my application using Backbone, I have a JSON object that tells what to display as HTML5 controls,

```
     "items": [
                { "key": "User.FName", "title" : "First Name" },
                { "key" : "User.LName", "title": "Last Name" },
                {
                    "key": "User.DateofBirth",
                    "title": "Date of Birth",
                    "type": "date"
                },

                {
                    "type": "submit",
                    "title": "Check",
                    "htmlClass": "chkbtn"
                }
            ]
```

And the value entered by the user are validated using this JSON schema,

```
"User" : {
         "required" : true,
         "minItems" : 1,
         "properties" : {
                    "FName" : { "required": true, "title" : "First Name", "type" : "string"},  
                    "LName" : { "required": true, "title" : "Last Name", "type" : "string"},                          
                    "Salutation" : { "required": false, "title" : "Salutation", "type" : "string"},
                    "DateofBirth" : { "required": true, "title" : "Date Of Birth", "type" : "string"}
        }
```

The required field validation is working fine. But I need to have a age restriction validation that the age must be 18 or older. How can I add the custom validation into this JSON schema so that it could be triggered in the UI?

Thanks in advance.

Backbone view code.

```
render: function () {

            // Code to add form from a template to el

            this.jsonForm = $("form").jsonForm({
                "schema": schema,
                "form": options,
                "value": vals
            });


        },

        submit: function (e) {

            var self = this;

            var err = this.jsonForm.validate();

            if (!err.errors) { // Code to persist} }
```

Comment: Where is the code that processes these JSON objects and creates the HTML elements, and validates the input from the elements? Unless you include that code, we won't be able to help a whole lot.

Comment: The code to render is simple actually. In the backbone view, a jsonform is added with the options (the JSON object), schema (the JSON schema) and the values from the db, if already added. On the button submit event, jsonform.validate() is called, before sending off the values to the api for persistence. I will edit the post to include the code.

Comment: Where does `jsonForm` come from? That's not a built-in jQuery function.

Comment: Aah, forgot the most interesting part. It uses the JSONForm plugin picked up from http://developer.joshfire.com/doc/dev/ref/jsonform/. That converts these schemas to HTML5 controls and provides validations too.